What are the not-winglet wingtips on the CL-415?
JohnK left a tantalizing "the weird turned up wing tips on the draggy slug CL-415 water bomber aren't winglets at all" comment in https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/52140.
So what are they, then?


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadair_CL-415

I know an aerodynamicist who was involved in the program who explained them to me years ago. They are not winglets or end plates. They are what you might call "dihedral tips".
They were added during CL415 development because the replacement of the CL215's round profile radial engine nacelles with the flat turboprop nacelles, during the redesign to the CL415, killed off too much of the aerodynamic dihedral effect created by the T wing-to-fuselage junction.
Recall that dihedral effect is a counter-rolling response to side slip when an aircraft banks, to provide stability in the roll axis. The 215/415 has zero geometric dihedral and depends solely on the wing/fuselage T junction for an aerodynamic dihedral effect to provide the desired roll stability (span wise flow is inhibited below the wing by the fuselage during side slip, but not above it, increasing lift on the low wing).
Thus roll stability was found to be degraded because the "high wing" configuration was effectively turned into a more of a "mid wing" by those big flat fin-like nacelles sticking up, inhibiting span wise flow (the same as a fuselage sticking up in a mid wing configuration) much more than the old round nacelles did. In other words, to the extent that a nacelle projecting above the wing profile acts as a flow fence, the flat TP nacelle is a much more efficient flow fence than the radial engine nacelle was.
The turned up tips generate the required counter-rolling response during side slip, sufficient to compensate for the effect of the flat nacelles, and restore the original roll stability. They are angled in a way that gets sufficient rolling moment with side slip (the axis of the lift force generated will pass above the center of mass) without creating much of a vertical lift component that would increase bending loads on the wing root.
In effect, they are a band aid solution to a problem introduced by the engine change, one of two unforseen surprises. Another problem was that the flat nacelles shifted the vertical neutral point (aerodynamic center) forward, reducing yaw stability and requiring the addition of finlets to the horizontal tail. This is similar to the effect of adding floats to landplanes, which is why you often see ventral fins, dorsal fins, or finlets added to floatplanes when floats are installed.

This maybe should be another question, but why does moving the aerodynamic center forward reduce yaw stability?

If you think of the entire aircraft as a weathervane (pivoting on its center of mass instead of a spike), you need the aerodynamic center of the vane to be behind the pivot so that the weathervane points into wind. You need more surface area behind than ahead of the pivot. On an airplane, adding surface area ahead of Cof G (the pivot), weakens the weathervaning tendency, the yaw stability. Look at the 415's nacelles & notice most of the side area is forward of the wing. When landplanes are put on floats, the exact same thing happens, thus the little finlets on floatplanes as with the 415.

It might be clearer to say that the dihedral tips were added when the aircraft design was retrofitted to have turboprop instead of radial engines. Otherwise, to a casual reader, it seems that they might have made the change during the initial design or something.

@le3th4x0rbot  Made a number of edits. Thanks.

In Germany those were once called "Lippisch-Ohren" ("Lippisch ears", after Alexander Lippisch, who first used them on his tailless designs).

Lippisch Storch IV in flight (picture source)
While the wingtip devices on the Storch and Delta ranges of designs helped in yaw control, later designs used them to correct lateral flight characterictics, like on the Heinkel 162.

Heinkel 162A with turned-down wingtips to correct for too much dihedral (picture source).

They are "end plates".

An end plate is a thin flat plate mounted at or near the tip of the wing, perpendicular to the wing surface and parallel to the airflow. It acts as a fence that opposes the spanwise flow near the tip of the wing.

not "winglets"

A winglet is a wing-like device that extends vertically or nearly vertically up from the tip of the wing. The winglet operates in the cross-flow generated by the tip vortex.
Unlike an end plate, which is flat, a winglet has an airfoil cross section and may also incorporate twist to optimize its aerodynamic effectiveness.

Reference: https://www.kitplanes.com/design-process-end-plates-and-winglets/
